# Cannot connect Objects to actions - no drag'n'drop option?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I have my `MainMenu.xib` with the Main Menu in it. I also have several `NSObject` subclasses as Menu Controllers, which are all represented in IB as objects, so that each Menu Item in the Main Menu corresponds to a dedicated Menu Controller

Whenever I try to drag'n'drop some menu item to its Menu Controller header and create an `IBAction` , Xcode does **not** give me that option. I suppose it's an Xcode bug, but I'm still confused...

When I created my first Menu Controller everything worked fine. However, now that I've added all Menu Controllers (the very same way as before), only the first one can be "linked" via IB.

What am I doing wrong? Any ideas on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, Make sure the following

1. you have used the word "IBOutlet" for each to be linkable
2. clean the code
3. restart xcode

And just to make it clear,if you think its a bug in your XCode copy, try creating a sample project and see if it also do the strange behavior

Comment: I found a way to "fix" it (will post it later as a separate answer) : I removed the existing classes and re-added them, and finally Xcode "saw" them. Arghh... :S